# VS Code adding space when compiling

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Writing code for c# shunting yard console calculator and vs code keeps adding space between my dictionary ref see below;

Before compiling;

```
if (operators.ContainsKey (Convert.ToString (ch)))
                return TokType.Operator;
```

After compiling;

```
if (operator s.ContainsKey (Convert.ToString (ch)))
                return TokType.Operator;
```

Dictionary reference above;

```
public IDictionary<string, Operator> operators = new Dictionary<string, Operator> {
        ["+"] = new Operator { Name = "+", Priority = 1 },
        ["-"] = new Operator { Name = "-", Priority = 1 },
        ["*"] = new Operator { Name = "*", Priority = 2 },
        ["/"] = new Operator { Name = "/", Priority = 2 },
        ["^"] = new Operator { Name = "/", Priority = 3, RHS = true }
    };
```

.csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"><PropertyGroup><OutputType>Exe</OutputType<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework></PropertyGroup></Project>
```

Please help... I'm going down inception of forums leading to nowhere.

Comment: It can do that if it can't find the variable with that name. Is there an `operators` variable declared somewhere?

Comment: Would you be able to add some detail about how this is being compiled?

Comment: @johnnyMopp added dictionary ref if that helps?

Comment: @OliverRadini does new edit help?

Comment: @Angelica thanks, it does make things slightly clearer. I was wondering what it is that you're doing in vscode to compile c# code, as I haven't done that before

Comment: operator is a keyword in C# try a different variable name.

Comment: @OliverRadini I’m using a couple of C# extensions. It has been compiling fine up until now. Just this one space it keeps adding is driving me insane.

Comment: Looks like it detects a variable name that starts with `operator` and because of being a reserved keyword cuts the variable name in two to correct your code. Looks like a VS Code bug, havent tested in Visual Studio. You could report to MS or use a variable name that does not start with `operator`. Obviously I dunno if the extension caused it or not, you could do some testing.

Comment: @Angelica do you know which extentions are being used? It seems like that'd help pinpoint the problem

Comment: @Ves wow... that made me feel beyond stupid. Thanks for your help. Fixed!

Comment: @Ves Anyway, `operators` should be a non problematic variable name. Looks like a IDE bug or plugins/extension bug.

Comment: @bradbury9 Thanks. Yeah disabled all the extensions one by one to try and find out what was happening but couldn't see anything. Will do that for sure!

Comment: As @bradbury9 this does seem to bug, but as a "seasoned-err old?" programmer I have been bitten by this class of problem so many times that it was my first guess. It would be a smart idea to track down exactly where that substitution is happening - I would expect other unexpected problems if this is happening to you.